# Php : 2 stored procedures called - "table name already exists"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have stored procedures called in my php file like this :

```
// PROCEDURE SQL
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tmp ORDER BY day ASC;";

            //CALL WITH SESSION VARS
            if(!$mysqli->query("CALL proc1('". $_SESSION['var1']." ', '". $_SESSION['var2'] ." 00:00:00','". $_SESSION['var3'] ." 00:00:00');"))
                die($mysqli->error);

            //EXEC SQL2
            $result = $mysqli->query($sql2)
                or die($mysqli->error);

            $i=0;

            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                //do some calculs on fetched results and get value from $row['x']


                if($row['r2'] == NULL){
                // SECOND PROCEDURE SQL
                // note : table name and procedure name are different
                $sql3 = "SELECT r2 FROM temp ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1;";

            //CALL WITH SESSION VARS AND LARGER DATE
            if(!$mysqli->query("CALL proc2('". $_SESSION['var1']." ', '2017-01-01 00:00:00','". $_SESSION['var4'] ." 00:00:00');"))
                die($mysqli->error);

            //EXEC
            $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql3)
                or die($mysqli->error);

            while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $value_r2 = $row2['r2'];
            }
```

The reason I want to do this is because I want to change the value of my data fetched in my first call if it returns null

As you can notice my two procedures are not the same and the table name of each procedure are different as well, so how can I have "temp table already exists" on my web page when I load this code ?

**EDIT :**

My procedures fetch results from my database and insert data into a temporary table.
The temporary tables doesn't have the same name.
Then, when I call the procedure I do a query on the temporary table associated.

Comment: Did you want to disclose the code that generates the error? I.e. the procedure. Probably you are creating a fixed name temp table in the procedure but but there can bo no two temp tables with the same name in one session.

Comment: Oh totally forgot I'll add some details

Comment: "temp table already exists" is quite a clear message, usually (if not always) shown when trying to create 2 tables with the same name. What are you doing in your procedures? Are you creating a table anywhere?

Comment: I can't give the code of the procedures it is hundreds on lines, but I have double checked, the temporary table of each one doesn't have the same name. @BrentLobbezoo In my procedures I create a temporary table and insert data into it

Comment: You might be calling your procedures in a loop. I can't really tell when `while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {` is closed. Maybe change your CREATE statements to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename` if you haven't already

Comment: That's why. I am calling the second procedure in the first while statement so it calls the second procedure for each row of the first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like there could be something broken or it might be a caching issue. Try one of the following:

```
FLUSH TABLES [tablename];
REPAIR TABLE tablename;
DROP TABLE tablename;
```

Remember to back-up your data.

Comment: Flush tables didn't solve the problem. I couldn't do the others commands on temporary tables that exists only when the procedures are called